# Extending a hug

Tags: expressions

Is the expression, I am extending a hug to you, only used when expressing sympathy or can it be used as an expression of love too?

Comment: Can you give us a context where this phrase occurs?

Answer (score 1):

When used to express love, *hug* on its own is enough.